# Simplest (completely) positive maps

Tags: c-star-algebras, positive-semidefinite

So, this question may be very simple, but I have an element $a$ in a C*-algebra, we can assume $a\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and therefore
$$ a = b a b^{-1} $$
has the same spectrum. Therefore, $x\mapsto bxb^{-1}$ maps positive elements to positive elements. But on the other hand the simplest completely positive map is $x\mapsto cxc^*$ and I don't get now why this is a positive map or where is the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

If $a$ is positive and $b$ is invertible, then $bab^{-1}$ is not necessarily positive. The problem is that for an element to be positive it does not suffice that its spectrum is contained in $[0,\infty)$, it additionally has to be self-adjoint. For example, the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
has spectrum $\{0\}$, but it is not positive (it's clearly not self-adjoint).

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is positive, we may decompose it as $x= vv^*$ and then
$$cxc^* = cvv^*c^* = cv(cv)^*$$
is positive. Hence, $x \mapsto cxc^*$ is positive.

Comment: Thanks, what is my mistake then? that $x\mapsto bxb^{-1}$ is not completely positive, right?

Comment: @bdt Your map is not positive, as it does not preserve self-adjoints element.